# Won't Draw Tiles?

Tags: java

Well, I'm making a relatively simple platformer game with java and I have a method that generates the level, but the tiles won't draw.

```
public void generateDungeon() {
    int y = 30;
    for(int x = 0; x < block[0].length; x++) {
        block[x][y] = new Block(new Rectangle(x * Tile.tileSize, y *      Tile.tileSize, Tile.tileSize, Tile.tileSize), Tile.basic);
    }
}
```

I want the Y to stay the same so that's why it has a set value.

That is where I think the problem lies, but here's the console message

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at mineandbuild.Player.isCollidingWithBlock(Player.java:82)
at mineandbuild.Player.tick(Player.java:22)
at mineandbuild.Component.tick(Component.java:89)
at mineandbuild.Component.run(Component.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The console says the problem is at this line of code:

```
public boolean isCollidingWithBlock(Point pt1, Point pt2) {     
    for(int x = (int) (this.x / Tile.tileSize); x < (int) (this.x / Tile.tileSize  + 3); x++) {
        for(int y = (int) (this.y / Tile.tileSize); y < (int) (this.y / Tile.tileSize  + 3); y++) {
            if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < Component.dungeon.block.length && y < Component.dungeon.block[0].length)
This line --->  if(Component.dungeon.block[x][y].id != Tile.air) {
                if(Component.dungeon.block[x][y].contains(pt1) || Component.dungeon.block[x][y].contains(pt2)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing out the x and y values for

```
if(Component.dungeon.block[x][y].id != Tile.air) {
```

You say that in the code before the value of y should stay the same, which means for every other index of y in the 2-d array they're set to null, but in the forloop you have this

```
for(int y = (int) (this.y / Tile.tileSize); y < (int) (this.y / Tile.tileSize  + 3); y++) {
```

which leads me to believe that you're trying to access indices that are null, then trying to access the "id" field, except that that object doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I totally understand.  Before the generateDungeon() method made the tiles generate randomly so: for(int x = 0; x < block[0].length; x++), also had a for(int y = 0; y < block[0].length; y++) before it.  Is there a way I could add that back but make it so that the Y does not increase?  If not, could you explain further please?

Comment: Assuming that makes a square, for(int x = 0; x < block[0].length; x++) with an inner for loop of for(int y = 0; y < block[0].length; y++) would put a block at every index. What you're doing now is to initialize new blocks only in a single column (row?). I dont fully understand what you're trying to do, but the easiest solution to me seems like adding another condition to the line where an error is occurring to explicitly check for nulls, like " if(Component.dungeon.block[x][y] != null && Component.dungeon.block[x][y].id != Tile.air) { "

Comment: Ah, ok that makes more sense. And yes, I'm trying to draw a row.

Answer (score 0):

block[x][y] might not have been initialized for all y values... as in genrateDunegeon() method you are initializing block[x][30] for all values of x.

So question is what for other values of y... did you initialized it in your not shown code snippet.

Until you will not initialize, exception will generate.

I think this may work.....(although not sure..)

```
public void generateDungeon()
{
  for(int x = 0; x < block[0].length; x++) 
 {
 for (int y=0; /*your termination condition like y<n */; y++)
  if(y == 30)
    block[x][y] = new Block(new Rectangle(x * Tile.tileSize, y *      Tile.tileSize, Tile.tileSize, Tile.tileSize), Tile.basic);
  else
    block[x][y] = new Block(null);
 }
  }
```

and handle null value in Block constructor.

Comment: Different error message when I try that.  It points to: block[x][y] = new Block(null, null);  I had to add the extra null for it to work just so you know.  Also, how would I handle the null value?  I have a pretty good understanding of java but I deffinately am not an expert on all the terminology or the language itself.